# Stop bash command without killing script

Tags: command-line, process-management, nmap

So I have the following command running from the shell

```
~/for ip in $(cat ip_list);do mkdir $ip; cd $ip; for vuln in $(snmap http);do nmap --script=$vuln $ip -oN $vuln;done cd ../ ; done
```

and it's been running fine for about a day. It's properly creating directories and navigating through them.

HOWEVER, one of the scripts is hanging now...

So what I'd like to do is use a key command similar to CTR+C that will kill this iteration of nmap but not exit the script that's running. That way I don't have to start all over or modify my ips list.

Comment: What happens when a `mkdir` fails? Are you okay with that case, or is there a `set -e` somewhere?

Comment: Ctrl-Z to suspend the process?   You can then background it with `bg` or resume it in the foreground with `fg`.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is for Bash.

You can use a trap for this. This is an illustrative example. To continue in the loop, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>. There's no way though to stop the script though apart from closing the terminal or killing it from another terminal.

```
#!/bin/bash

trap ps SIGINT
for i in a b c d;  do
    for j in w x y z; do
        echo ----$i$j------ && ping stackexchange.com -c 10
    done
done
exit
```

Your script will look something like this (after some of my improvements), but notice it's not been tested:

```
#!/bin/bash
trap '' SIGINT
for ip in $(cat ip_list); do
    mkdir $ip && cd $ip &&
    for vuln in $(snmap http);do
        nmap --script=$vuln $ip -oN $vuln
    done &&
    cd ..
done
```

The changes I introduced like `&&` are preventing from entering logical paths that can lead to error. If possible it's safer to impose such contstraints. When it's put this way:

```
mkdir $ip; cd $ip;
```

if the directory can't be created, then `cd` leads to error.

When you put it this way:

```
mkdir $ip && cd $ip
```

if the directory hasn't been created for some reason, then no `cd` is attempted. When you keep all the commands from `mkdir $dir` through `cd $dir` to `cd ..` chained with `&&`, the logic is clear and the structure will not go wrong. When you use `;` and fail to create the directory, then you fail to enter it, but you will possibly not fail to change to `..`.

Answer (score 1):

I know I posted and then answered but I wanted to preserve this answer in the case anyone else came across this problem.

What I did was from another shell, I ran `ps -a` then I found my nmap process and killed it with `kill proc-id`. The script continued on to the next iteration.